# Le sens commun de "la sonde"

Tags: étymologie

Ce sont des sens de "sonde" dans la dictionnaire:

- tube que l'on insère dans le corps
- appareil pour mesurer la profondeur de l'eau
- appareil pour creuser
- appareil que l'on envoie dans l'espace pour étudier les astres

Y-a-t-il un sens commun? Ce sont des choses complètement différents!

Answer (score 1):

Le sens premier est celui d'un objet (par exemple un bâton) qui sert à jauger la profondeur de quelque chose: on l'utilise en l'enfonçant dans une profondeur.
Les autres sens dérivent de là, soit dans le sens de quelque chose qu'on insère pour effectur une mesure, soit dans le sens de quelque chose qui explore un espace inconnu (ex: sonde spatiale).

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais que lorsque j'entends le mot "sonde" le sens qui me vient en tête serait un peu le même qu’éclaireur. Je m'explique: une sonde est un objet que tu envoies en terre inconnue pour y retrouver ou découvrir  quelque chose. J’espère que cette vulgarisation t’aide à voir différemment le mot "sonde".

Comment: Lorsque *sonde* représente et le capteur et le logiciel ou la personne qui le manipule, on parle de *sondeur*. Le *sondage* d'une population se fait par des sondeurs qui interrogent un 'panel' de personnes sélectionnées, afin d'éclairer les media sur une tendance/situation sociale.